# Mutiple OU's in SVN LDAP Authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, svn, active-directory, ldap

Basically I'm atempting to authenticate SVN via LDAP and have done successfully with my example below:

```
AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://IP/OU=USERS,DC=domain,DC=domian,DC=domain?sub?objectClass=organizationalPerson" "NONE"
```

however including the folder USERS in AD I also need to use the folder "ServiceAccounts" so I am wondering if something like the following would work:

```
AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://IP/OU=USERS,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=domain,DC=domian,DC=domain?sub?objectClass=organizationalPerson" "NONE"
```

Thanks in advance

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide multiple AuthLDAPUrl entries, you need entry AuthBasicProvider (in connection with AuthnProviderAlias entries).  They are documented at the [usual place](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authn_core.html) for Apache 2.3 and newer.